# Why is UUID nil in simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

I'm developing a tvOS app fully with **Swift**.

In `AppDelegate.swift`, I try to print `UUID` under `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

However, error message shows `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

The app was actually functional and worked well before. This bug happened after I **reset** the simulator.

Here is how I get `UUID`.

```
let UUIDValue = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
let newuuid = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "uuid") as? String
print ("This device uuid is " + newuuid!) // error message happens here
```

I believe every device should contain a **UUID**, but how it happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get `newuuid` from `UserDefaults`:

```
let newuuid = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "uuid") as? String
```

but you have zero entries in `UserDefaults` after resetting the Simulator and did not set a value for key "uuid" yet.

This does not make much sense, but fixes the issue:

```
let uuidValue = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString
UserDefaults.standard.setValue(uuidValue, forKey: "uuid") // add entry in UserDefaults
let newuuid = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "uuid") as? String
print ("This device uuid is " + newuuid!)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

UUIDs are only generated for real devices and not for iOS simulators because hardware devices get registered with Apple network to get access to device tokens.

Comment: But before I reset the simulator, it did return a UUID for me, like `EAB07A5E-F5AE-4677-A815-3C638HK42`.

Comment: You _do_ get a `identifierForVendor`. on simulator

Comment: @shallowThought does this change after each restart?

Answer (score 0):

> UDID and Device Token for Push are simulated that's we can send push
>   to simulator. they are only for development perspective. UDID keeps
>   changing for simulator. Same for messages, app links, mails as their
>   template can see on simulator bur couldn't test it.UDID will change each time that the application is re-installed